# Why does function always return 9?

Tags: python

I am looking for an explanation of how this code works. I am unsure of a few things. Is `return` dominant over the `print` function which is why 9 always prints? What does the `put` mean? Variable `val` is my `tuple`. Does `val` need to be called?

```py
def put(X):
  return [9]
val = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
y = put(val)
print(y)
```

Comment: def put(X):
  return [9]
val = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
y = put(val);
print(y)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This should be python, yeah?

Comment: Yes, python. Thanks

Comment: Your code always prints `9` because `y` is always `9` because the function `put` always returns `9`. There is no such thing as a dominant function, functions are executed in sequence. The list you assigned to `val` is also never used and therefor cannot contribute to the output. I think it would be most effective to read some basic guide on python syntax to understand the basic concepts before diving into debugging. Good luck and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Let's grab us the disassembly of the python code real quick:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object put at 0x01FAC7B0, file "test.py", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('put')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (put)

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             12 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
             14 LOAD_CONST               5 (6)
             16 LOAD_CONST               6 (7)
             18 LOAD_CONST               7 (8)
             20 BUILD_LIST               6
             22 STORE_NAME               1 (val)

  4          24 LOAD_NAME                0 (put)
             26 LOAD_NAME                1 (val)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             30 STORE_NAME               2 (y)

  5          32 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             34 LOAD_NAME                2 (y)
             36 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             38 POP_TOP
             40 LOAD_CONST               8 (None)
             42 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object put at 0x01FAC7B0, file "test.py", line 1>:
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (9)
              2 BUILD_LIST               1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

The number at the very left is the line number. If you're familiar with the concept of  [stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), this shouldn't be hard to understand.

I admit, my python is utterly weak - but it should be enough to explain your questions:

> Is return dominant over the print function which is why 9 always
> prints?

No, that's not what happens here. With `def` you're defining a function called `put` with one argument `X`. The indentation marks the function's body, which is just returning a list containing the constant value `9`.

> what does the put mean?

It's the method's name.

> Variable val is my tuple. Does val need to be called?

You are not "calling" your variable, you're defining a list with the constant values. Other than that, this definition is utterly useless, because we're not doing anything with it.

---

So, now to the part I guess you actually wanted to code (?):

```
def put(X):
  val.append(X);
val = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
put(9);
print(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

@maio290's answer is great, but I want to a more basic, high-level one.

**TL;DR** When you call `y = put(val)`, the `put` function gets a pointer to `[1,2,4,6,7,8]` as input and returns `[9]` as output - thus, `y` will always be `[9]` (no matter what input you give it).

---

### Slightly Longer Answer

It seems like your question centers around what happens when you call `y = put(val)`, so I'll focus there. When you call `y = put(val)`, there are two, high-level components to consider:

1. **Input** (in the form of arguments)
2. **Output** (in the form of a return statement)

So let's look at the input we give to the `put` function and the output it gives back to us:

#### Input

When you call `y = put(val)`, the `put(val)` is executed first. We can say that we are passing `val` as an argument into the `put` function.

The snippet below adds a print statement in the `put` function showing the value of the argument `X` that we provided as input:

```py
def put(X):
  print(X)  # this will print [1,2,4,6,7,8]
  return [9]
val = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
y = put(val)
```

#### Output

Now, what is the output of the `put` function? That is, what does it return or give back to us? The `put` function returns `[9]` as seen below:

```py
def put(X):
  return [9]  # <- this line shows us what is returned from the `put` function
```

So, no matter what input you give to the `put` function, it will always return `[9]` (you can test this out ).

---

Note: If you want to add `9` to the `val` list, you should do:

```
val = [1,2,4,6,7,8]
val.append(9)
print(val)  # [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the explanation I was looking for. That breaks it down for me.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Can you accept or upvote this answer (if it was helpful)?